# backbone.js model.clear with no defaults

Tags: backbone.js

When I create a new backbone.js model, the attributes from "defaults" are NOT ignored, they become the initial values for my model.
Why are they ignored when I call "clear" on a model.
Is there any reason behind it?
Why should I want a state, where all properties of my model are 0 or ""(spaces) when I have "defaults"?
Can anybody give me a real world example for that?

For instance, in one of my models there is a property called "status". The initial value is "x", but the user can change it to "b" or "u". ""(space) is no valid value.  Therefore in the model, I have

```
 defaults: {
   "status":  "x"
 }
```

In the detail component, where the user can edit the values of a model, he has a button called "erase". When he does that, the model gets the initial state. In this case I will never need a function to set all properties to zero or spaces.

It would have been easy for the backbone.js author to check in the "clear" method, if the model has "defaults", and if so, delete all values and then get the defaults.

Thanks alot in advance
Wolfgang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like it *overwrite it*!

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  clear: function(options) {
    Backbone.Model.prototype.clear.apply(this, arguments); // or something like this
    return this.set(_.clone(this.defaults));
  }
});
```

and now on you can use your custom model as a basis for all your models

```
var MyModel = Model.extend({...});
```

If doing this quick thingy bothers you, you can post this to backbone.js' git [issues](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar need. Because authors of frameworks don't use them by themselves, they can't foreseen all real world use cases. Better to ask directly https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone

Anyway, it's javascript

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.resetToDefaults = function() {
    this.clear();
    this.set(this.defaults);
};
```

Comment: I prefer this over overriding clear() method just to keep default behaviours as they are and not confuse any other developers that works on the same project.